# Requisição AJAX não funcionando

Tags: php, ajax, requisição

Eu tenho uma função que chama um ajax para salvar no banco. Todas as minhas outras requisições POST eu fiz desse jeito e deu certo. Agora eu não sei o que aconteceu, to sem ideia, já mexi em muita coisa aqui e não deu certo. 
Se alguém poder me ajudar.

```
                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    async: false,
                    url: "passageiro_ajax.php?case=salvarPassageiro",
                    data: "prefixo=" + prefixo_id + "&linha=" + linha + "&dia=" + dia + "&hora=" + hora + "&nomeFinal=" + nomeFinal + "&catraca=" + catraca + "&catracaFinal=" + catracaFinal + "&dinheiro=" + dinheiro + "&isento=" + isento + "&transporte=" +transporte + "&estudante=" + estudante + "&livre=" + livre,
                    success: function(d) {
                        alert("Amostragem de passageiro feita com sucesso ");
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(d) {

                    }
                });
```

Lá na pagina do ajax. passageiro_ajax.php

case 'salvarPassageiro':

```
    $linha = $_POST['linha'];
    $prefixo = $_POST['prefixo'];
    $dia = $_POST['dia'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $nomeFinal = $_POST['nomeFinal'];
    $catraca = $_POST['catraca'];
    $catracaFinal = $_POST['catracaFinal'];
    $dinheiro = $_POST['dinheiro'];
    $isento = $_POST['isento'];
    $transporte = $_POST['transporte'];
    $estudante = $_POST['estudante'];
    $livre = $_POST['livre'];


    $querySalvar = "insert into amostragem_passageiro
     (linha_id, prefixo_id, dia, hora, nome_final, catraca, catraca_final, dinheiro, isento, transporte,
      estudante, livre , usuario_id) 
     values ('{$linha}','{$prefixo}', '{$dia}','{$hora}','{$nomeFinal}','{$catraca}','{$catracaFinal}',
     '{$dinheiro}','{$isento}','{$transporte}','{$estudante}','{$livre}''{$usuario}')";


    mysqli_query($conexao, $querySalvar);

    echo json_encode($prefixo);

    break;
```

Eu faço esse echo pra retornar e sempre retorna null, já tentei de tudo
Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas que podes alterar ai:

Está fazendo a chamada AJAX como "GET" mas está recebendo no php como POST ($_POST['linha']...), tens que definir se vais trabalhar com GET ou POST;

Outra coisa, estás passando a data como query param, nesse caso podes colocar direto como uma lista de objetos:

```
  data: { 
    prefixo: prefixo_id, 
    linha: linha, 
    dia: dia,
    //...

  },
```

Espero ter ajudado